# Code auto-completion trouble with Rcpp and Netbeans/Eclipse

Tags: r, netbeans, rcpp

I'm trying to write some Rcpp code using Netbeans, primarily using the IDE for the method look-up / code completion. I've set up the project to include the R/include and R/library/Rcpp/include folders, and it seems this -almost- works. For example, if I write

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

Rcpp::CharacterVector x;
x. // hit CTRL+SPACE to pop-up methods available to x, no hits
```

However, if we look at what a CharacterVector is, we see:

```
typedef Vector<STRSXP> CharacterVector
```

which is defined in Rcpp/include/vector/instanstiation.h, so it should (?) just be inheriting all the methods available to the Rcpp::Vector class. Equivalently, if I write

```
Rcpp::Vector<STRSXP> x;
x. // hit CTRL+SPACE, and I do see a bunch of methods available
```

it does work. Furthermore, if I just copy the typedef declaration into my current source file, then the auto-completion does work.

So, I guess my question is - why does Netbeans struggle in finding the methods available to Rcpp::CharacterVector but not Rcpp::Vector?

Ultimately, it's not a big problem, but I am curious...

Comment: Surely you mean `Rcpp::Vector<STRSXP>`, `Rcpp::Vector<CHARSXP>` makes no sense, and probably does not work.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right - I miswrote. Should be STRSXP. Edited!